# Is it possible to hide the wire in the edit mode?

Tags: python, edit-mode, wireframe

I am working on models made by photogrametry so I had really dense mesh. I wanted to know if it is possible to hide (or make it transparent) the wire of the mesh when I m in the edit mode?
I m using blender 2.79. And I already try to make it less thick and to change the color in the user preference menu, but I can't hide it.
Thank you if you can help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is the option which was formerly dubbed, <kbd>Only Render</kbd>.

The icon to the left of the red-arrow is the toggle button, the icon to the right has a bunch of other viewport toggle draw options.

[image]